# Is there a way to edit the type of credentials project in Google API console?

Tags: google-api, google-console-developer

I have project created in https://console.developers.google.com  as web application. Is there a way I can edit this and change it to an installed application?

Web client

[image]

Other

[image]

Thank You!

Comment: I think you need to create another one with the correct type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have created the credentials they are static until you delete them but you can simply go in and create new credentials.

[image]

You can create more several credential's for your project it doesn't matter.   However if you wont be using the other one its probably a good idea to delete it.